# Find the time lag for a wave

Tags: digital-communications, signal-analysis, autocorrelation, cross-correlation

suppose that we have a wave which has some peaks in some indexes like 2,12,25,... and otherwise zero.

I want to extract the time lag or lags between peaks of a signal. could anyone help me ?

[image]

Comment: Do you know the sample rate?

Comment: Can u put a picture up?

Comment: the sampling rate is 16000 you can see pic in following link: https://www.researchgate.net/file.PostFileLoader.html?id=516bd03fd2fd64e64e00004b&key=9c960516bd03f33ad8

Comment: @AliBodaghi: do you want to find the peaks on the image, or in the sequence of numbers? could you provide the sequence in simple text form?

Comment: I want to find time lag to remove other spurious peaks. you can suppose some high peaks with special distance from each other with some other random and weak peaks between 2 high peaks.

Answer (score 1):

The time lag is equal to the index difference times the sample period.  The sample period is:
$$
T_s = \frac{1}{f_s} = \frac{1}{16000} = 62.5\mu s
$$
Thus, the time lag from the first peak to the second is $(12 - 2) * T_s = 625\mu s$.  The time lag from the second peak to the third is $(25 - 12) * T_s = 812.5\mu s$.

Comment: Thanks for your respond. However, my question is removing the spurious peaks as you seen in Figure part B by using time lag between peaks.